# What is the error in my code for the n queen puzzle?

Tags: c, debugging, n-queens

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
char a[10][10];
int n;
int feasible(int row,int col)
{
    int i,j,tcol;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]=='Q')
                break;
        }
        tcol=j;
        if(col==tcol || abs(row-i)==abs(col-tcol))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
void nqueen(int row)
{
    int i,j;
    if(row<n)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(feasible(row,i))
            {
                a[row][i]='Q';
                nqueen(row+1);
                a[row][i]='.';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe solution is:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                printf("%c\t",a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
}
            int main()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter the number of queens:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
    nqueen(0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The function feasible is to check whether a queen can be placed in the row & column passed.

The function `nqueen` gives all the possible solutions for the problem.
I don't get any output on the screen. Please help!

Comment: Please fix your indent. Four spaces per line is all you need to format text as code, you have way more even on lines that shouldn't have any C indent.

Comment: n,i and j are not initialized!

Comment: What have You done to find the problem?

Comment: What do you mean you 'don't get any output'?  Does it not print "Enter the number of queens:"?  Try flushing the output.  Better yet, don't scanf the parameter but take it from the command line.

Comment: I mean it takes the input but gives no output.

Comment: @Zelldon, n, i and j are indeed initialized, i and j in for loop and n - global - with the call to scanf

Comment: @PW. ah thanks i didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check your board for feasability, you should only check the rows that you have already placed queens in:

```
int feasible(int row, int col)
{
    int i, j, tcol;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 'Q') break;
        }
        tcol = j;

        if (col==tcol || abs(row - i) == abs(col - tcol))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

For each row `i` with `i < row`, there is a queen. All other rows don't have queens yet and `tcol` equans `n`, the value it had when it fell off the loop. I guess that the diagonal check is accidentially true sometimes, cutting a perfectly valid queen placement short.

Instead of finding the queen in each row, you could check three paths - straight up, left diagonal (`l`) and right diagonal (`r`) for all rows:

```
int feasible(int row, int col)
{
    int l = col;
    int r = col;

    while (row--) {
        l--; r++;

        if (a[row][col] == 'Q') return 0;
        if (l >= 0 && a[row][l] == 'Q') return 0;
        if (r < n  && a[row][r] == 'Q') return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Another way to represent the board is to keep the rank of the queen for each file, so that you don't have to search. This will make printing the board slightly more complicated, though.